# C# to Sort by Last Created (oldest record) & Limit results to 20 records from DynamoDB Table

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How to apply Sort by Last Created (oldest record) & Limit results to 20 records from DynamoDB Table using BatchGetItemAsync Method. Thanks in Advance.

```
        var table = Table.LoadTable(client, TableName);
        var request = new BatchGetItemRequest
        {                     
            RequestItems = new Dictionary<string, KeysAndAttributes>()
        {
            { TableName,                      
                new KeysAndAttributes
                {
                    AttributesToGet = new List<string> { "ID", "Status", "Date" },
                    Keys = new List<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>>()
                    {
                      new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                      {
                        { "Status", new AttributeValue { S = "Accepted" } }
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        }                    
        };

        var response = await client.BatchGetItemAsync(request);
        var results = response.Responses;
        var result = results[fullTableName];
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do what you're asking for with `BatchGetItemAsync`. That call is to get specific records, when you know the specific keys you are looking for. You'll need to use a query to do this, and you'll want to get your data in a structure that supports this access pattern. There was a really great session on DynamoDB access patterns at re:Invent 2018. I suggest watching it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k